# Expo not starting any dev tools in the local host

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

This problem is very weird. I am running an expo based react native app and everything was working fine until a week back. I resumed my work only to find the expo start doesn't start up the dev tools on the localhost - port 19002. I keep getting 'cant reach this page' error message. The logs are as below

```html
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
```

It was working perfectly and all of a sudden this happens. I used to get Tunnel ready message and everything was perfect. I can't proceed with my development because the dev server would not even start. I did install FortiClient VPN recently but I deleted all the associated files and I am no longer on it. I am clueless why this is happening.

I tried the following:
    1. Uninstalled expo cli, reinstalled it.
    2. Cleared all vpn files to the best of my knowledge.
    3. Ran other simple react native projects. I encountered the same issue.

Nothing seems to work. Can somebody please help? Is there anything really trivial I am missing here? I have a demo to show in a few days. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it after pulling an all-nighter. I was using anti-virus software and the firewall protection was on. I switched it off and that did the magic. Not sure how that got turned on though.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. Believe it is related to versions of dependencies.

Using expo init I was given a package.json file that looked like this below. Metro bundler wast not starting up in the browser on localhost:19002:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
}
```

I manually copied over the configuration I had from another project where metro bundler was displaying in the browser

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
},
```

I ran npm install. Then on the next npm start metro bundler was displaying in the browser

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is Turning off your firewall.

Other than that I would assume you can create a rule or an exception to allow expo to continue working with your Antivirus.